# How to determine an invalid CFSocket

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sockets

How can I avoid, to send data via `CFSocketSendData` to an invalid socket?
I've try to determine the socket state with `CFSockerIsValid`, but this method
returns still true when the other side is close.

How can I determine if the socket is valid? In order so avoid Errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the other side closes the socket, your callback (which you specified in CFSocketCreate) will get invoked with a callback type of kCFSocketDataCallBack, yet the data will be empty.  Test for it like this:

```
void SocketCallback (CFSocketRef s, CFSocketCallBackType callbackType,
                 CFDataRef address, const void *data, void *info)
{
    if (callbackType == kCFSocketDataCallBack) {
        NSData *nsData = (NSData *)data;
        if (nsData.length == 0) {
            NSLog(@"got kCFSocketDataCallBack, but with 0 bytes -- connection terminated");
            // do whatever you want to do here when connection is dropped
        }
    } else {
        NSLog(@"SocketCallback type %d", callbackType);
    }

}
```

You can set a flag there and use that to know that your connection is dropped, and then when you go to write to a dropped connection, attempt to reconnect or notify the user or whatever you want to do.